# Write a program to perform set operations.

Tags: code-golf, set-theory, stateful

Your task is to write a program to perform set operations. The operations and arguments are taken from command line in the format `program operation [argument]`. There are four operations:

1. **1**: clears the set. no arguments. exit code 0.
2. **2 integer**: adds the `integer` into the set. exit code 0.
3. **3 integer**: removes the `integer` from the set. exit code 0.
4. **4 integer**: queries the set for `integer`. exit code 0 if integer exists or 1 otherwise.

The integer is a 64-bits integer. Shortest program wins. You can, of course, use a temporary file. However, watch out the space and time limit.

Example:

```
$ program 1 ; echo $?
0
$ program 2 10 ; echo $?
0
$ program 4 10 ; echo $?
0
$ program 3 10 ; echo $?
0
$ program 4 10 ; echo $?
1
$ program 2 10 ; echo $?
0
$ program 1 ; echo $?
0
$ program 4 10 ; echo $?
1
```

Comment: @Joey. Yes. That's why you should use a file.

Comment: Your 4th test assert an exit code of `1` which is not according to the specification (where `3` would always return `0`).

Comment: @Joey: thank you. I missed that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Bash -- 54 chars

```bsh
case $1 in
1)rm *;w;;
2)>$2;;
3)rm $2;w;;
4)<$2;;
esac
```

Notes: Outputs to stdout/stderr in some scenarios. Empties working directory when clearing the set. Uses one file for each set element. The purpose of `;w` is to exit with status 0.

This appears to comply with all the rules.

Comment: I find it brilliant that you use separate files for each argument.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash: 106 chars

```
touch f
case $1 in
1)rm -f f;;
2)echo $2>>f;;
3)grep -vx $2 f>g;mv g f;;
4)grep -x $2 f&>/dev/null;;
esac
```

Counting newlines as one character. Requires two temp files and POSIX grep. I'm unclear as to the precise constraints on temp files: if I can have two kicking around all the time then I can save 8 chars by writing to g rather than /dev/null in case 4.

Comment: If you add number '123' and then query for '23' what's the exit code?

Comment: @Eelvex, good catch. I had -x on one grep but not on the other.

Answer (score 2):

## Python - 167 chars

```py
import sys,shelve as S
x,A,E=S.open("x"),sys.argv,exit
A[1]<'2'and E(x.clear())or'3'>A[1]and E(x.__setitem__(A[2],1))or'4'>A[1]and E(x.__delitem__(A[2]))or E(A[2]in x)
```

You need to create the temporary file like this

```py
python -c 'import shelve;shelve.open("x","c")'
```

Answer (score 2):

## bash, 74

```
case $1 in
1)>f;;
2)echo $2>>f;;
3)sed -i /^$2$/d f;;
4)grep ^$2$ f;;
esac
```

**note** I'm not plagiarizing [Peter Taylor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1183/write-a-program-to-perform-set-operations/1188#1188), it's just that it's not working with `[ test ]`s

Answer (score 1):

## PHP - 204 characters

```php
<?
$s=unserialize(file_get_contents('f'));
$a=$argv;
$o=$a[1]--;
$a=$a[2];
--$o?(--$o?(--$o?die(!isset($s[$a])+0):$s=array_diff_key($s,array($a=>1))):$s[$a]=1):$s=array();
file_put_contents('f',serialize($s));
```

Added some linebreaks to make it a tad more readable.
This throws a warning to screen when run for the first time, but otherwise, it does as asked.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby - 146 characters

```rb
a,b=ARGV
File.open('x','a+'){|f|s=eval(f.read)||[]
s=[]if a=='1'
s+=[b]if a=='2'
s-=[b]if a=='3'
f.puts s.inspect
exit a=='4'?(s.index(b)?0:1):0}
```